# vim scripting - count number of matches on a line

Tags: vim

I'm trying to count the number of regex matches in a line, and I need to use the result in a vim function. For example, count the number of open braces.

```
function! numberOfMatchesExample(lnum)
    let line_text = getline(a:lnum)

    " This next line is wrong and is the part I'm looking for help with
    let match_list = matchlist(line_text, '{')
    return len(match_list)

endfunction
```

So I'd like to find a way in a vim function to capture into a variable the number of regex matches of a line.

There are plenty of examples of how to do this and show the result on the status bar, see
`:h count-items`, but I need to capture the number into a variable for use in a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `split()` function splits a string on a regular expression. You can use it to split the line in question, and then subtract 1 from the number of resulting pieces to obtain the match count.

```
let nmatches = len(split(getline(a:lnum), '{', 1)) - 1
```

See [`:h split()`.](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#split%28%29)

Comment: after I read the question, I thought of `split()`, then saw your post... +1

Answer (score 3):

For the special case of counting a single ASCII character like `{`, I'd simply `substitute()` away all other characters, and use the length:

```
:let cnt = len(substitute(line_text, '[^{]', '', 'g'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hack with `substitute()` with side effects:

```
function CountFigureBrackets(lnum)
    let line=getline(a:lnum)
    let d={'num': 0}
    call substitute(line, '{', '\=extend(d, {"num": d.num+1}).num', 'g')
    return d.num
endfunction
```